# How to Enable buttons when an Item is clicked/selected using AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-activity

There are 4 buttons which need to be disabled until an item resourced through an array is selected/clicked using

> AutoCompleteTextView

I tried using the following code to perform this action. However, the buttons still remain enabled in all instances. Could someone correct me where I went wrong?

```
final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_new_sale);
final Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_dues);
final Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_returns);
final Button btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_history);

//Initializing an OnItemClick Listener for AutoCompleteTextView
home_search.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        btn1.setEnabled(true);
        btn2.setEnabled(true);
        btn3.setEnabled(true);
        btn4.setEnabled(true);
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you mean "remain disabled?"

Comment: Yes, to enable the buttons only when an item is clicked using AutoCompleteTextView. My apologies. Till now I was thinking that something was wrong with my java code. Unfortunately, I haven't disabled the buttons using xml {android:enabled="false"}.
@ekchang your sentence found me the solution. Thanks

Comment: Glad it was able to point you in the right direction!

Comment: I have yet another query though. How can I notify the user, that an Item needs to be clicked in order to enable the buttons. Unless the user is notified of this, the user might get on to assume that the app is kaputt/failed. I mean something like a Toast notification. Any suggestions?

Comment: One way I've seen this done is to create a "tutorial" by masking the entire app with a dark background and a semi transparent alpha with some arrows / instruction that describe what things may do, then allow the user to dismiss the tutorial with a confirmation button (like "Ok, got it!") and then never open this tutorial overlay again. 

Another is to have dedicated tutorial activity that loads if it is the first time an app has been launched.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the AutoCompleteTextVierw, but it seems that your OnItemClickListener enables all buttons no matter which item is clicked.

I suggest you use a switch in the onItemClick() to make sure you enable only the correct button.